# Is it possible to expose property file of java web application to the user and get it updated or deleted

Tags: java, property-files

I have property file in my java web application, I want this to be visible to the user, who can edit its values or delete the values as and when he wants, is this possible with property files?

myproperty.properties

```
logFileName=application_stdout.log.gz
displayName=demo
executors=2
```

Comment: Define user. Why would a client of your application need to know, or care, where the logs are located?

Comment: consider user as an admin, he can edit the log location or file name